# Outlook Addin Best Practice - Where to store the configuration when you deploy the addin from a server?

Tags: windows, outlook, windows-registry, configuration

I've seen some posts about this, but i have a specific requirement.

What is the optimal solution to save the configuration for an Outlook (2007/2010) Addin when you want to also make sure that the configuration can also be automatically deployed through Windows Server means (e.g. the Addin should be installed by the Administrator on a multitude of PCs and the Admin should be able to supply the default config).

I think registry would be a save way, i know that you can deploy changes automatically in a cooperate envirenment - or is the app.config better suited for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think registry is the best place.